# Deploying a standalone java application with hsqldb

Tags: mysql, hsqldb

I have a Java application that uses a local mysql db. I want to give this to clients so they can install it in their machines without installing mysql. I did some research online and many people suggest using HSQLDB. My question is can I use HSQLDB with hibernate? Do I just need HSQLDB and hibernate or do I need Spring as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use HSQLDB with Hibernate with or without using the Spring Framework.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to set up a hibernate HSQLDB application but what is the difference between hsql and an in-memomry sever?